# Dropping <some command> | netcat to the background via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe, background-process, netcat

For a project, I am using a remote machine to run a binary and pipe the output to a log server via netcat.

Example:

```
ssh <user>@<host> -p <port> -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -i key nohup <some long running command> | nc <log_host> <log_port> &
```

What I want is for the ssh connection to exit as soon as the commands go into the background.

The process successfully drops to the background (I believe), but I am unable to figure out how to terminate the ssh connection.

I have tried to use screen too, but that was after messing with this way a lot and frankly I was very tired and getting really confused, and had trouble figuring out the various different problems with it. I believe a second set of eyes is pretty crucial to make progress at this point.

Just for note, I have tried a simpler test command and that doesn't work either. `ssh` waits for the entire three seconds, rather than forking off the background command and immediately terminating.

```
ssh <user>@<host> "nohup sleep 3 && echo test | tee ~/test.log & exit"
```

Comment: The simpler test command works for me! Looking at your original command, I've had this kind of problem with longing running commands, and the problem turned out to be a connection timeout. I fixed it by supplying a `ServerAliveInterval` option to `ssh`, so `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 "command"`.

Comment: Even with your option, the simpler command waits until the command is finished. I tested this by running "watch -n .5 cat test.log" on a separate ssh connection, and changing the sleep time to 10 and adding your option. The file doesn't change until right after the ssh connection terminates.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you wanted. See my answer below.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071447/13317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem with `ssh` waiting for I/O from standard output and standard error.

Try redirecting all output to `/dev/null`:

```
ssh user@host "(nohup sleep 3 && echo test | tee ~/test.log) >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Comment: Wow, this works! Didn't think about that, thank you <3